# How to make relation between two tables in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to make relation between these two tables, I have created two tables emp and dept as shown below,

```
create table emp (
    empno number(4) constraint empnopk primary key,
    ename varchar(10) constraint enamenn not null,
    mgrno number(4) constraint mgrnofk references emp(empno),
    sal number(10) constraint salck check(sal between 2000 and 5000),
    age number(2) constraint ageck check(age>20),
    mobno number(10) constraint mobuq unique
); 

create table dept (
    deptno number(10) constraint deptnopk primary key,
    dname varchar(10) constraint dnamenn not null,
    loc varchar(10) default 'xyz'
);
```

as the emp table is the master table and dept table is child table,to make relation between these two tables i have given query

```
alter table emp
add constraint deptnofk foreign key(deptno) references dept(deptno);
```

when i give this query it is showing ORA-00904:"DEPTNO": invalid identifier

What may be the problem?

Comment: Make sure your requirements are correct.  Can a person be in more than one department?  In some companies a manager may manage two departments.  And, sometimes employees can work parttime for two different departments.

Answer (score 5):

Your emp table does not have a deptno field.  Add this as a number(10) and it should work better.

Comment: The last query does not add the deptno column, it only tries to add the foreign key constraint.  It specifies the column only so the foreign key constraint will know how to make the relationship.  The column must exist prior to creating the foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

You need add deptno field in your emp table, because you are creating a foreign key from table emp to dept by droptno field.